# Can I get the following author-deleted question undeleted?

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete

Can this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497737/parsing-an-expression-of-prefixes-to-a-tree-in-ruby) be un-deleted?

It was not a bad question, but needed some improvement that was suggested in comments.  I had also provided an initial answer, with the expectation that it could be improved with more info from the OP.  The OP even thanked be for the answer,  but then just deleted the question.

### Update

To clarify the reasons for the request (based on comments below).

1. The OP is somewhat new.
2. The question asked needed more info, particularly clarification as to the expected output should be.
3. I provided what I thought was a non-trivial answer.
4. OP was being "coached" via comments, both by myself and another higher rep contributor, on how to improve his question
   so that an improved answer could be provided.
5. The OP acknowledged my answer was helpful to him (in a comment)
6. Later that day or the next day the OP then deleted the question, along with my answer.

So while it is not clear why the question, along with my answer were deleted,  it's entirely possible the OP felt he got what he wanted from the answer and then simply deleted the question,  thinking this was the right way to proceed, which I don't think is the intent of the site.

Comment: So, the question was incomplete, your answer is a "best guess" that requires the question to be improved, and the OP deleted the question... Why should this be undeleted? 

The OP apparently decided the question was no longer necessary.

Comment: Also, if you truly believe it's a good question, you can re-ask it but more clearly. You must have a really good reason to undelete against the author's wishes

Comment: If a question gets revived by random request, what's the point of deleting them?

Comment: @Desdenova: This isn't a random request. This is coming from the person who answered the question. If someone takes the time and effort to put together a non-trivial answer to a question, and that question then gets deleted, taking their answer with it, it's not unreasonable for them to ask if *maybe* the question and their answer could be restored.

Comment: @BoltClock But the question, by the answerers own admission, isn't a good question, and doesn't contain enough information to be answered *by the admission of the person that answered it*.  That makes the request rather unreasonable.  Someone providing an answer that *they don't even know the correctness of*, and that is on a question *they don't think is a good question* doesn't seem like any basis at all for undeleting a question.

Comment: The question just needed a little more detail that the OP, it was not "incomplete"

Comment: @nPn What do you think incomplete means?

Comment: Why not do as Erik says, and just post your answer under a new question? Since the asker wants that question deleted, and it would require additional work to be a good question anyway, wouldn't be easier just to post a new (better) question and self-answer it?

Comment: I can understand and accept the reasons for denying this request, but based on the number of down-votes, it seems like I should have somehow known not to even make this request, and since there is an up-voted answer I don't think I can even delete the question.  I hate to leave such a poor question can someone suggest a way to improve this question?

Comment: [Voting on meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Votes are often used to express (dis)agreement with the general premise of the Meta question. These votes won't affect your main site reputation.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks that helps,  so I will just take it as most people don't think the question should be un-deleted,  which I am fine with.

Comment: @nPn: Yea, I think that's what you should take from the votes here.

Comment: @Servy: I never said that the question *should* be undeleted. I said that it's not unreasonable or strange for the person who answered the question to be interested in getting it undeleted. Desdenova called it a "random" request, but it's from someone who contributed to the question, not some "random" passer-by with no personal stake whatsoever.

Answer (score 10):

The question needs to be edited before it should be undeleted, otherwise, it would be an incomplete question that should be closed.

The person that should be making those changes, is the OP of that question.

Since the OP is the one that deleted that question, I'd wager it's unlikely that the OP is interested in improving the question.

The *author* of the question deleted that question. You'll need something more substantial than *"I've written a non-trivial answer"* to overrule that. Especially considering your answer is a bit of a "best guess", considering the information missing in the question.

---

Update: 3 users deemed it necessary to undelete the question. The OP of that question re-deleted it. I ***strongly*** suggest leaving the question alone now.